# Node.js: Unable to compress response using express

Tags: node.js, express, compression, gzip, http-compression

I am using express version 4.13.4 and the following code for my app.js. I have tried changing the location of `app.use(compression())` which did not show any effect. when I run the application I saw no evidence of compression in viewing the chrome dev tools response headers i.e it doesn't have the gzip content-encoding header.
    I am new to node js.I want to gzip compress my response to browser. Please help me fix this issue.

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
app.use(compression());
var settings = {
    UiServerPort:         8080, 
    ApiServerHost: "localhost", 
    ApiServerPort:       12121
};

app.use('/ui', express.static('ui')); 
app.all('/api/*', function (req, res) {
    var options = {
        host: settings.ApiServerHost,
        port: settings.ApiServerPort,
        path: req.url.substring(4), 
        method: 'POST' 
    };

    var requestData = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) { requestData += data; });
    req.on('end', function () {
        var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
            var responseData = '';
            res.flush();
            response.on('data', function (data) { responseData += data; });

            response.on('end', function () {
                res.statusCode = response.statusCode;
                res.write(responseData);
                res.end();
            });
        });
        request.write(requestData);
        request.end();
    });
});
app.listen(settings.UiServerPort)
```

Comment: Can anybody help me fix this issue? I have recieved no answer yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you saw  " Vary   Accept-Encoding " ??  if you don't use compression , this won't show. and I paste your code ,but It can't run.

Comment: The Accept-Encoding on browser Request Header says: gzip, deflate. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
app.use(compression())
```

You should add this piece of code :

```
app.use(compression({filter: shouldCompress}))

function shouldCompress (req, res) {
   if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {
       // don't compress responses with this request header
       return false
   }

  // fallback to standard filter function
   return compression.filter(req, res)
 }
```

PS : it works for me.